# BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF, new expression, ambiguous default type conversion

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I would think this should work:

```
#include "boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp"

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, StrongInt);

int main()
{
    StrongInt len (100);
    int *heapInts = new int [len];
}
```

gcc 4.8.2:
    ./StrongTypeTest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    ./StrongTypeTest.cpp:8:30: error: ambiguous default type conversion from ‘StrongInt’

> ```
> int *heapInts = new int [len];
>                          ^
> ```

./StrongTypeTest.cpp:8:30: error:   candidate conversions include ‘StrongInt::operator const int&() const’ and ‘StrongInt::operator int&()’

Comment: Interestingly, Clang does not give this error.

Comment: try changing to `size_t`, as that is what `new` expects (note - this is called the *new expression*, `operator new` is slightly different)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes that will work (and thanks for the note, I'll change the title). But the following works(can't get linebreaks in comment): `#include <iostream>  #include <cstdint>   #include "boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp" BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, StrongInt); void aFunc(std::size_t val) { std::cout << val << std::endl; } int main() { StrongInt len (100); aFunc(len); }